# Does there already exist an R package that can print any list to the console as a tree (using ASCII symbols)?

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust

I would find it convenient to be able to print out any list-mode R object using the same format as `str.dendrogram`. I wrote my own function that kind of works, but there's no point in duplicating effort. So, does anybody know of any packages that already do this? Or a way to easily create a fake dendrogram or hclust object from an arbitrary nested list without having to actually cluster it?

Thanks.

Comment: What about `str(my_list)`?

Comment: Two problems -- first of all, as far as I know, `str()` descends into every subsettable object, and dumps everything to the console. Second, it uses the less readable '...' on the left side instead of vertical and horizontal lines which make it easier to keep track of hierarchical relationships.